# Cómo relacionar a través de un condicional, columnas de distintas hojas

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formato-condicional

NNecesito que para cada 'Order Id' que diga "Completado" , en la siguiente hoja cada vez que aparezca ése número de orden, coloque completado en una columna adyacente.

Consideraciones: Como este "excel" (hoja de cálculod e Google) es para Appsheet, no puede tener macros ni tablas dinámicas, además con la limitación que la planilla debe estar generada en Drive. También intenté con `Sumar.si.conjunto`, pero por una extraña razón, al cambiar el número de pedido, dejaba de contar y fallaba.

Adjunto foto, espero que se entienda.[image: Descripción]

Comment: ¿Qué opciones intentaste? Coincido que con BuscarV debería funcionar.

Comment: Intenté varias cosas, sumar.si.conjunto me pareció la mas acertada, pero fallaba, tambien intenté la función si, etc. Pero probé BuscarV y me arroja todo "Completado" (tuve que cambiar la primer condición por "Completado", sino me tiraba "N/A". La idea sería que al lado del número de cliente (independientemente de las veces que aparezca dicho número) aparezca el estado que aclara en la hoja anterior. Le respondo a ambos y le agradezco

Comment: Algo debes estar haciendo mal, porque con un BUSCARV funciona perfectamente. Con SUMAR.SI imposible, porque lo que quieres obtener al final, es un texto, no un número.

¿Cómo has formulado el BUSCARV? Comparte tu hoja porque algo has hecho mal

Comment: Agrega los datos de ejemplo como texto así como las fórmulas que has intentado.

Comment: En una hoja, puede aparecer, x ej. el Order ID (555) y su Estado (Completado) y otro ID (777) con su estado (Reservado). Quizás la situación que puede estar afectando al buscarv es la sig. que a veces en la primer hoja aparece una sola vez el ID con el estado. Y en la otra hoja puede aparecer 3 o 4 veces el mismo número de ID en distintas filas, y la intención es que en c/fila donde aparezca ese ID, aparezca tambien el estado pertinente. =BUSCARV(Orders!B:B,Orders!A:B,2) . Pongo así porque debe traspasar cualquier estado, no solo el completado

Comment: Muchachos, a todos los que comentaron, la solución fue la función " =BUSCARV(B2,Orders!A:B,2,FALSO) "
Se agradece!

Comment: Genial, me alegra que lo solucionases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un BUSCARV debería servir, algo tipo `=BUSCARV(B2;Order!A:B;2;FALSO)`

Comment: Te agradezco, en el comentario de arriba respondí mi situación.